# MAtch links with regexp in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

Trying to match links with regular expression

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) FROM as795_sh404sef_urls WHERE newurl REGEXP 'index\.php\?option\=com\_ohanah&Itemid=108\&id\=\d+\&lang\=en\&view\=event' AND rank<>0 GROUP BY oldurl
```

But returns no results.

The type of links are

```
index.php?option=com_ohanah&Itemid=108&id=4778056&lang=en&view=event
index.php?option=com_ohanah&Itemid=108&id=4779002&lang=en&view=event
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: use `[0-9]+` instead of `\d+`

Comment: Still does not return any results. It looks like there is a limit on the length of regex

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simple LIKE, that matches both the strings before and after your id?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) FROM as795_sh404sef_urls
WHERE newurl LIKE 'index.php?option=com_ohanah&Itemid=108&id=%' AND newurl LIKE '%lang=en&view=event'
AND rank<>0 GROUP BY oldurl
```